# Instagram-like filters color transform matrix

Tags: image-processing, matrix, colors, image-manipulation, imagefilter

I'm trying to create some instagram-like filters for an iOS app, and i need the 4x5 color transform matrices that can achieve the following filters (or similar):

- Nashville
- Hemingway
- Jarques
- Cross Process
- Hazy Days

You can use this page as a reference http://techslides.com/demos/canvas/instagram.html

Does anyone knows these matrices?, or knows how can i obtain them?

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: Any luck? I too am using color matrices to try to achieve these same results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app was being developed using Adobe Air, and i used this library to apply the filters.

https://github.com/inspirit/GPUImage

I was not able to implement the filters described in the Question, and end up using photoshop curves to achieve the effects. If someone wants to know the implementation i used, feel free to send me a message. I don't know if i can share for copyright reasons.